# Which channel to add to anaconda to use python=3.5.9 in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5

I'd like to use a anaconda environment with the latest python 3.5.* version.
I've tried `conda install python==3.5.9`. The message displayed was

```
 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: 

  - python==3.5.9

 Current channels:

 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

So I guess my appropriate question is:

**Which channel I have to add to my Anaconda to get the latest python 3.5.* version?**

kind regards,

Pat

Comment: conda-forge stopped supporting python 3.5 quite some time ago and the latest version in the official channel is 3.5.6. So it seems you will not make it beyond 3.5.6 only relying on widely supported channels.

Comment: ok, thank you! (Wondering why, just to understand why there are further versions of 3.5.)

Comment: For conda-forge the rationale was this: packaging for an extra python version costs extra time on the continuous integration services. When python-3.7 was released support of 3.5 was dropped in order to save resources. I don't know why the support for the official channel was dropped.

Comment: _I'd like to use a anaconda environment with the latest python 3.5.* version. I've tried conda install python==3.5.9._ If you want the latest available version of Python 3.5 installed, then use `conda install python=3.5`.